# Connected vs. Necessarliy connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ and $B$ be connected subsets of a topological space $(X,T)$ such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

$(i)$ If $(X,T) = \Bbb R$, prove that $A \cap B$ is connected.

$(ii)$ If $(X,T) = \Bbb R^2$, prove that $A \cap B$ is necessarily connected.

Connected spaces in $\Bbb R$ are intervals, and two intersecting intervals is an interval.

**My question is:  What is the difference between the two questions concerning "connected" vs "necessarily connected?"**

Comment: I don't know but for (i) it's true that $A\cap B$ must be connected, since the only connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are intervals.  In case (ii) $A\cap B$ need not be connected, consider two half circles that meet in two points.  So "necessarily connected" apparently is weaker than "connected".

Comment: Can you post the definition of "necessarily connected" given in your book?

Comment: That isn't defined anywhere in the book I'm reading.  I had a guess that it meant something to do with "necessary vs. sufficient" but I couldn't see a way.

Comment: I think it's a typo, probably intended to say "prove that $A\cap B$ is _not_ necessarily connected." It's not hard to find a counterexample.

Comment: Connected spaces in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not necessarily path connected

Comment: Well I googled around and I can find no definition of "necessarily connected".  Without a definition we obviously cannot answer this question.

Comment: @JackLee That seems to make more sense given the example that Gregory Grant provided.